# 1970's sci-fi novel titled "Planet of the Gworfs" (or perhaps "Gwarfs")

Tags: story-identification, novel

In 1977-78 I bought a sci-fi paperback, I remember titled "Planet of the Gworfs"  (or perhaps "Planet of the Gwarfs")

The cover featured your standard, over-the-top 70's sci-fi cover painting with garish green colors, some kind of wolfman-looking creature and a large toad.

It may have been a compendium, but I recall it being a short novel, approx 200-250 pages.

Answer (score 30):

A(n incrementally refined) Google Images search for

> "planet of the" -apes cover -doctor -daleks

uncovered this:

[*Planet of the Gawfs* by Steve Vance](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0843911131), which according to [this blogpost](https://cheapscifi.blogspot.de/2008/07/planet-of-gawfs-by-steve-vance-1978.html) first appeared in 1978.

The cover graphic looks a lot like what you describe: It contains

- "garish green colors": the whole image has a greenish hue
- "some kind of wolfman-looking creature": at least a guy with very thick facial hair
- "a large toad": I'd have classified the humanoid as reptile-like, but your mileage may vary

[image: front cover as described above]

Comment: Not my down vote... but it appears as if your search criteria lacks a certain amount of sincerity.

Comment: @TGnat: What do you mean by "sincerity"? As usual with web searches, I started with one search term or phrase, and then gradually added or excluded additional terms, one by one, to filter away the false positives until I would spot a desirable result, and the cited set of search terms is simply what resulted from that process. I didn't think that needed explaining, but just in case that really was a reason for the downvote, I added a brief clarification to my answer.