# Book involving banished mutants teenagers: strong male, green girlfriend and friend with four arms

Tags: story-identification, mutant

Please help me find this book; it has been bothering me for years!

A future after a virus has been cured. The cure causes mutation on the descendants. Feared these mutants are banished to another planet used as a prison. Main characters are teenagers, protagonist is lion-like with strength and agility, he has a green skinned girlfriend and a four armed nerdy friend. That's all I can remember. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Approximately when did you read it? Any idea on what the cover looked like or names of the characters?

Comment: I read it about 25 years ago, when I was a teenager. No idea on cover or names. Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

I just stumbled across this, I read the same book as well about 15 years ago. Its called Planet of the Gawfs by Steve Vance. It was a great sci-fi read, however. Don't get your hopes up. He never wrote another book in the supposed 'series' as the book would have led you to believe. Vance continued his writing career mostly in his involvement in The Simpsons comics through the '90s.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! We are a Q/A site not a forum so your answer would be better if you removed the tangential information and opinions and added details about why this story matches what is in the OP.

Comment: As @TheLethalCarrot says, if you could add why this book is a good match it would make this an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 1):

As per Hailey's answer, this could very likely be *[The Planet of the Gawfs](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/36009630-planet-of-the-gawfs)* by Steve Vance. This [blog post](http://cheapscifi.blogspot.com/2008/07/planet-of-gawfs-by-steve-vance-1978.html), used as support of the same book being provided as an answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/114555/23243), provides more information.

[image: Front cover of *Planet of the Gawfs*]

> According to the prologue, in 1997, the earth was hit by a mysterious plague that wiped out most of population. Some people who got the plague survived, but their children started being born with various deformities and super powers. An anti-mutant campaign began, with a powerful politician declaring "God's blueprint only!" These Gawfs, short for "God-awful freaks", were soon rounded up en masse and shipped to a planet called Thear to live out their lives with their own kind.

....

> Eli, the hero of our tale, was long able to blend in with the humans by shaving his whole body and capping his fangs. When he used his superhuman strength to save a friend, though, his friend turned him in, and off to Thear he was sent. Life on Thear turned out to be nasty, brutish, and short, with monsters that want to eat you and savage tribes that want to kill you (and maybe eat you). Eli, along with a motley crew of strongmen, monkeymen, four-armed dudes, ten inch tall chicks and other mutants, want nothing more than to escape the planet and seek justice. And so off on the adventure we go.

[This Goodreads review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1154085623?book_show_action=true) mentions the girlfriend has green skin:

> Eli hooks up with Holly, a blonde with green, rubbery skin, and they settle into a small village. Eli's particular mutations are advantageous in this environment. He's covered with black fur (he kept it shaved on Earth), has extra-long, sharp canines, superhuman strength and speed, and heightened senses. He makes a few friends, and also earns the enmity of a horned, red-headed, and super-strong Irish mutant named Finnegan.

I am willing to cede the contents of this answer to Hailey should they return, but it turned into too long of an edit to just change their answer for them.